# Storing ArrayList<? extends BaseModel> in Realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

I have an `ArrayList<? extends BaseModel>` that I'd like to store in Realm.

I have several classes that extend BaseModel and they're all stored in this ArrayList. Will Realm just do the right thing if I store this on disk? Each child class may have it's own additional members and methods.

I should probably just try testing this myself, but I'm away from my dev machine, so thought I'd ask anyway and answer it myself if no one gets to it first.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can store list of `BaseModel` by call `copyToRealmOrUpdate()`, if `BaseModel` extend of `RealmObject` class or if implement `RealmModel` interface:

```
void storeListToRealm(List<? extends BaseModel> models) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(models);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Otherwise, you need to create "StoreModel", which you can store to realm, and mapping from `BaseModel` to `StoreModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Realm generates a `RealmModuleMediator` class that has the following code:

```
public String getTableName(Class<? extends RealmModel> clazz) {
    checkClass(clazz);

    if (clazz.equals(com.yourpackage.somemodel)) {
        return io.realm.SomeModelRealmProxy.getTableName();
    } else if (clazz.equals(com.yourpackage.anothermodel)) {
        return io.realm.AnotherRealmProxy.getTableName();
    } else if ...
```

Looks to me like it makes no difference whether you pass in the subclass or the super class.